Approximation of a Riemann sum.
Given a twice continuously differentiable function $f\in C^2([0,1])$, is there a theorem/result/algorithm on how to place $0<x_1<\ldots<x_{n-1}<1$ so that adding $x_0=0$ and $x_n=1$,
$$
\sum_{p=0}^{n-1}\int_{x_p}^{x_{p+1}} \left| f(x_p)- f(t)\right| dt 
$$
is optimal in some sense (maybe that means of order $1/p^2$) ?
Something like "f" dependent Chebyshev points for integration, or Gauss points, perhaps?
This is probably classical in numerical analysis, but I don't know what I am looking for.
